# WPF MMV ICollectionView Filter on many atributes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a problem I created using datagrid and some text boxes filtering system that uses commands so the xaml part would look like :

```
           <GroupBox Header="Filtry">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Label Content="Imie" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstnameFilter" MinWidth="50" Text="">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <b:PropertyChangedCommandBehavior DependencyPropertyName="Text" PropertyChangedCommand="{Binding FirstameCommand}" />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBox>
                    <Label Content="Nazwisko" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtLastnameFilter" MinWidth="50" Text="">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <b:PropertyChangedCommandBehavior DependencyPropertyName="Text" PropertyChangedCommand="{Binding LastnameCommand}" />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
```

Data grid:

```
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding firstname}" Header="Imię" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding lastname}" Header="Nazwisko" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding email}" Header="E-Mail" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Using ICommand Ive managed to create simple filter that would look like

```
    public void Filter(object obj)
    {
        this.Candidates.Filter = item =>
        {
            Candidate candidate = item as Candidate;
            return candidate.firstname.Contains(obj.ToString()) || candidate.lastname.Contains(obj.ToString());
        };

        this.Candidates.Refresh();
    }
```

He is being called out by command:

```
        this.FirstameCommand = new RelyCommand(Filter, param => this.canExecute);
        this.LastnameCommand = new RelyCommand(Filter, param => this.canExecute);
```

And here lies the problem. It works perfectly when I filter using only names, but when I call LastnameCommand Im having null reference exception in filter method, witch should be as when I type in the name last name is empty.

Now is there a way to aggregate filters so it will sort for example if I put name fist it will filter all names and if I put last name it will filter all names and last names??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the Filter method doesn't throw any exceptions:

```
public void Filter(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return;

    this.Candidates.Filter = item =>
    {
        Candidate candidate = item as Candidate;
        if (candidate == null)
            return false;

        string name = obj.ToString();

        return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(candidate.firstname) && candidate.firstname.Contains(name))
            || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(candidate.lastname) && candidate.lastname.Contains(name));
    };
    this.Candidates.Refresh();
}
```

But if you want to filter on both the first name and the last name simultaneously you should bind the TextBoxes to two source properties of your view model and call the Filter method in the setters of these:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFirstnameFilter" MinWidth="50" Text="{Binding FirstNameToFilterOn}" />
<Label Content="Nazwisko" />
<TextBox x:Name="txtLastnameFilter" MinWidth="50" Text="{Binding LastNameToFilterOn}" />
```

---

```
private string _f;
public string FirstNameToFilterOn
{
    get { return _f; }
    set { _f = value; Filter(); }
}

private string _l;
public string LastNameToFilterOn
{
    get { return _l; }
    set { _l = value; Filter(); }
}

public void Filter()
{
    this.Candidates.Filter = item =>
    {
        Candidate candidate = item as Candidate;
        if (candidate == null)
            return false;

        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstNameToFilterOn) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(candidate.firstname) || candidate.firstname.Contains(FirstNameToFilterOn))
         && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastNameToFilterOn) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(candidate.lastname) || candidate.lastname.Contains(LastNameToFilterOn));
    };
    this.Candidates.Refresh();
}
```

Otherwise the Filter method doesn't know anything about the other name, i.e. it only knows the name (first name or last name) that you pass as an argument to the command.